# How to convert a row of csv file into column using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have this:
[There are six rows in csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MYEV.png)

and I need to convert in this formate:
[convert into columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tI3q.png)

I tried convert a column into rows and I got successfully

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.read_csv('source.csv', header=None) #reading it as csv for now
columns = x[0] #convert questions label column to list
columns.tolist()

output
['Period', 'B_date', 'C_date', 'Year', 'Day of period', 'label']
```

but I am confused how to convert rows into columns

Comment: I'm not sure if you just want to swap your row and column values, but if so transpose might work for you (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html )

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment, try Transpose...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('source.csv', header=None)
df.T
```

**Outputs:**

```
    0   1           2           3       4   5
0   1   1-Jan-21    31-Jan-21   2021    31  FY21
1   2   1-Feb-21    28-Feb-21   2021    28  FY22
2   3   1-Mar-21    31-Mar-21   2021    31  FY23
3   4   1-Apr-21    30-Apr-21   2021    30  FY24
4   5   1-May-21    31-May-21   2021    31  FY25
5   6   1-Jun-21    30-Jun-21   2021    30  FY26
6   7   1-Jul-21    31-Jul-21   2021    31  FY27
7   8   1-Aug-21    31-Aug-21   2021    31  FY28
8   9   1-Sep-21    30-Sep-21   2021    30  FY29
9   10  1-Oct-21    31-Oct-21   2021    31  FY30
10  11  1-Nov-21    30-Nov-21   2021    30  FY31
11  12  1-Dec-21    31-Dec-21   2021    31  FY32
```